# What is the meaning of the $0<x, y<\infty$ bound in this joint PDF?

Tags: notation, density-function

I'm given a joint PDF,

\begin{equation}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-(\frac{x}{y}+y)}y^{-1} & \text{  , } 0<x,y<\infty\\
0 & \text{ , otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}

From which my professor asks us to find the marginal PDF $f_{Y}(y)$. He says:
"Clearly, $f_{Y}(y)=0$ for $y\leq 0$." I do not understand why $f_{Y}(y)=0$, this is not clear to me. As far as I can see, if $y\leq0$, then $y<\infty$ and therefore $f_{Y}(y)\neq0$ for $y\leq 0$. So what am I not seeing?

Comment: $0<x,y<\infty$ is the same as saying $0<x<\infty,0<y<\infty$, or simply $x>0,y>0$. The condition $y<0$ corresponds to the 'otherwise' part of the joint pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x,y<\infty$ is equivalent to

> If $0<x$ **and** $0<y$ **and** $x<\infty$ **and** $y<\infty$.

For $y\le0$, $y$ is indeed strictly less than $\infty$, but $0<y$ does not hold. Thus the condition is not satisfied and, by definition, we have $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Excellent, I see I misinterpreted it, thank you. As Stubborn Atom mentioned in the comments, it says $0<x<\infty$ **and** $0<y<\infty$. I thought it was $0<x$ **and** $y<\infty$!

Comment: Ah, I guess that was a tricky comma :D